# Non-PDF special ignored! Figures created using \special command

Tags: pdftex

I have several figures stored as .tex files that were generated by the Japanese language application [WinTpic](http://aogaeru-lab.my.coocan.jp/). From my understanding, WinTpic merely generates a large list of `\special` commands in a .tex file which you can then use `\input` to import figures drawn from its drawing interface.

For example, here is a truncated version of a WinTpic output:

```
\unitlength 0.1in
\begin{picture}( 45.4400, 13.1600)(  3.6000,-16.7600)
% CIRCLE 2 0 0 0
% 4 392 1192 418 1211 418 1205 418 1205
% 
\special{pn 8}%
\special{sh 1.000}%
\special{ar 392 1192 32 32  0.0000000 6.2831853}%
\end{picture}%
```

If say the above code block were stored in figure1.tex, we would then use  something like

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\input{figure1}
\caption{A WinTpic example.}
\end{figure}
```

to generate the picture. However, pdfLaTeX gives a Non-PDF special ignored! error for all of these commands. From my own research, I am aware of (although I do not fully understand) the driver dependent issues which leads to pdfLaTeX ignoring these commands by design. However, I have far too many complicated figures stored in this manner to merely recreate them in TikZ. As such, I need a way to convert these files into a usable format or force pdfLaTeX to run these commands.

Comment: It could work directly in the document with auto-pst-pdf, but I would probably put the pictures in `standalone` documents and create pdf's with latex->dvips->ps2pdf. These pdf you can the include with \includegraphics in your normal document.

Comment: I've not tried it but http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tpic2pdftex.1.html (and the script does seem to be installed in texlive 2017)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. These solutions seem beyond the scope of my knowledge at the moment (shell-escape for auto-pst-pdf; extra hoops I've never done before for latex->dvips->ps2pdf and first time seeing AWR for tpic2pdftex). I am installing texlive 2017 now and will go from there, but I don't think I will be able to update whether I can get these to work soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could not get the auto-pst-pdf to work for the life of me, but latex->dvips->ps2pdf worked like a charm. Thanks!