# Converting images created from \special,\put,\makebox commands into pdf using standalone

Tags: margins, standalone, crop, dvips

This question is related to an older question of mine: [Non-PDF special ignored! Figures created using \special command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384118/non-pdf-special-ignored-figures-created-using-special-command?noredirect=1#comment950805_384118).

In this question, user Ulrike Fischer suggests solving my problem by creating `standalone` documents and then using `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.

This has solved my problem at the time, however I have encountered a different problem. I am now working with figures that include not only `\special` commands but `\put` and `\makebox` too. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{picture}( 45.7200, 10.3100)(  3.6000,-15.9100)
\special{pn 8}%
\special{sh 1.000}%
\special{ar 936 596 36 36  0.0000000 6.2831853}%
\special{pn 8}%
\special{sh 1.000}%
\special{ar 936 1136 36 36  0.0000000 6.2831853}%
\put(9.3600,-16.7600){\makebox(0,0){$H_0$}}%
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

After using `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`, the resulting figure will be cropped such that it will be the smallest box containing all parts of the figure generated from `\special` commands and ignoring `\put` and `\makebox`.

As of now, the easiest fix I can think of is to instead compile the figures in the article document class and use adobe to crop them by hand, but I would prefer to use that solution as a last resort.

Comment: As you are using specials, TeX has no idea of the nature of the output you are creating. Either you'll need to rework by hand or convert to some format that does log bounding box info (most obviously TikZ).

Comment: Have you tried the pstricks package?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I took a look at some documentation for pstricks, but I am not sure what I am supposed to do with it. Are you suggesting I rewrite all the figures using pstricks commands?

Comment: I don't use it myself.  I sort of hoped it would handle \special postscript commands.

Answer (score 1):

As already mention in the comments by other users, TeX can't take the size of content into account which are added as specials, because this is only processed later by e.g. `dvips`.

You could add the required border manually using the `border` key of the `standalone` class. You can use e.g. `ghostscript` to scan the resulting PDF for the actual used size and use this information to calculate the border. A way easier way is to simply use `pdfcrop` on the PDF, as it uses `ghostscript` internally. As it only takes visible material into account, you need to add a large margin beforehand, e.g. `border=10cm` in the above case, then crop it down with `pdfcrop` again.

So

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=10cm]{standalone}
...
```

and then

```
latex <filename>.tex
dvips <filename>
ps2pdf <filename>.ps
pdfcrop <filename>.pdf
```

and you get `<filename>-crop.pdf` as an result.